# Simple Nested IF syntax error - pl pgsql

Tags: plpgsql

I'm getting a syntax error with the following code:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION max_bit_number(this_val bigint, prev_val bigint) RETURNS bigint AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF this_val < prev_val THEN
        IF prev_val > 4294967296 THEN
            RETURN (9223372036854775807 - prev_val) + this_val;
        ELSE RETURN (4294967296 - prev_val) + this_val;
    ELSE RETURN prev_val - this_val;
        END IF;
        RETURN;
    END;
 $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you fix your confusing indentation, you can see the missing `END IF;` immediately. The last `RETURN;` makes no sense btw. Remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `END IF` missing before the `RETURN`.